How can I use SMO (SQL Server Management Objects) with OleDB Provider (MSOLEDBSQL/MSOLEDBSQL19)?
Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16, the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB providers (SQLNCLI or SQLNCLI11) are not recommended for new development.
But my understanding is that SMO (Sql Server Management Objects) uses the SQL Server Native Client OLE DB providers natively. So how do I plug in the the OLEDB Providers MSOLEDBSQL/MSOLEDBSQL19 ? I was not able to find any documentation saying SMOs were being deprecated. I use SMOs in PowerShell scripting. I tried a round about way of plugging in a OleDBConnection but that did not work very well. The $Master object was $null.
Here's a sample:
$objConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDB;Provider=MSOLEDBSQL19;Persist Security Info=False;Auto Translate=False;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=false;Connection Timeout=600;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

$ServerConnection= new-object  Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection $objConn

$SQLServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $ServerConnection

$Master = $SQLServer.Databases["master"]


SMO is not deprecated. It uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and you need that package and the SqlConnection class, not OleDbConnection

Of course actually using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient directly from PowerShell isn't exactly trivial. In the past I found it was easiest to install the latest available SqlServer PowerShell module and then use Add-Type -Path ... to load the Microsoft.Identity.Client and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient assemblies from there (pick the coreclr or .NET Framework platform versions according to whichever version of PowerShell you're using).

@Charlieface, Can you clarify ? Per Microsoft  "The SQL Server Native Client OLE DB providers (SQLNCLI or SQLNCLI11) are not recommended for new development."  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient uses SQLNCLI or SQLNCLI11 implicitly, right ?

No it doesn't, not sure why you thought it did. It relies on an internal native DLL called sni.dll which is entirely unrelated.

Resonpse from @Charlieface posted in comments,
SMO is not deprecated. It uses Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, and you need that package and the SqlConnection class, not OleDbConnection.  It relies on an internal native DLL called sni.dll , not to be confused with SQLNCLI or SQLNCLI11
